# Quotient of integral representation of archimedean exterior square L-function

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, cv.complex-variables, l-functions

Let $\psi$ denote a non-trivial additive character of $\mathbb{R}$ and $r=2n$ be a positive even integer. Let $(\pi,V)$ denote an irreducible generic admissible Casselmann-Wallach representation of $G_r=\operatorname{GL}_{r}(\mathbb{R})$.

Further, let $\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)$ denote the Whittaker model of $\pi$ and $\mathcal{S}_n$ denote the space of Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We set $\sigma_{r}\in\operatorname{GL}_{r}(\mathbb{R})$ to be the permutation matrix:

$$
\sigma_{r}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
1 & 2 & \cdots & n & n+1 & n+2 & \cdots & 2 n \\
1 & 3 & \cdots & 2 n-1 & 2 & 4 & \cdots & 2 n
\end{array}\right).
$$

Now consider the family of integrals:

$$\mathcal{J}_{2n}(\pi)=\operatorname{span}\{J(s,W,\Phi):W\in\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi),\Phi\in\mathcal{S}_n\}$$
defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
&J(s, W, \Phi) \\
&=\int_{N_n \backslash G L_n} \int_{\mathcal{N}_n \backslash \mathcal{M}_n} W\left(\sigma_{2 n}\begin{pmatrix}
I_n & X \\
& I_n
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
g & \\
& g
\end{pmatrix}\right) \psi^{-1}(\operatorname{Tr} X) d X \Phi\left(e_n g\right)|\operatorname{det}(g)|^s d g,
\end{aligned}
$$

where:

- $e_n=(0,0,...0,1)\in\mathbb{R}^n.$
- $N_n$  is the group of upper triangular matrices with unit diagonal over $\mathbb{R}.$
- $\mathcal{N}_n$ is the space of upper triangular matrices over $\mathbb{R}.$
- $\mathcal{M}_{n}$ is the set of $n\times n$ matrices over
  $\mathbb{R}.$

Further, let $L(s,\pi,\wedge^2)$ denote the exterior square L-function associated to $\pi$ defined via the archimedean local Langlands correspondence.

Is it known that the the complex function

$$s\rightarrow\frac{J(s,W,\Phi)}{L(s,\pi,\wedge^2)}$$

is entire for every $W\in\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)$ and $\Phi\in\mathcal{S}_n$?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is in the literature, but it should be provable (with a fair bit of work).